# Why does Tolkien keep referring to the Fellowship as "the Company"?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, wording-choice, the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I noticed that the group making the journey from Rivendell is called "the Company" rather than "the Fellowship". The title of the book has "The Fellowship", yet he doesn't once (so far) call it the "Fellowship" in the book.

Not that they aren't a "company", but it seems to me as they are to be the "Fellowship of the Ring" rather than the "Company of the Ring". Why then does he use "Company" in the book?

Answer (score 2):

A "company" can be a group of people that are associated with each other, especially for the purpose of accomplishing a goal or task. It doesn't have to refer exclusively to a commercial entity.

Webster's [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/company) a company as follows:

> 1a: **association with another : fellowship**
> // enjoy a person's company
> b : **companions, associates**
> // know a person by the company she keeps
> c : visitors, guests 
> // having company for dinner
> 2a : **a group of persons or things**
> // a company of horsemen
> b : a body of soldiers
> *especially* : a unit (as of infantry) consisting usually of a headquarters and two or more platoons
> c : an organization of performing artists a company of actors
> d : the officers and crew of a ship
> // The captain called a meeting of the ship's company.
> e : a firefighting unit
> // A hose company was first to arrive at the scene of the fire.
> a : a chartered commercial organization or medieval trade guild
> b : an association of persons for carrying on a commercial or industrial enterprise 
> // electric companies
> // a publishing company
> c : those members of a partnership firm whose names do not appear in the firm name
> // John Doe and Company

Definitions 1a, 1b, and 2a are especially applicable, and all describe exactly what the Fellowship was. (In fact, definition 1a actually lists the word as a synonym of "fellowship").